# Как работает копирование без настройки конструктора копирования? c++

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор, конструктор-копирования

В коде что ниже есть такое копирование:

```
MyClass A (1);
MyClass B (A);
```

В объекте А у меня есть указатель * data на динамическую область памяти
Дальше идет цикл которым мы заполняем наш массив
Как дальше происходит копирование прям пошагово?

1)У меня в объекте В вновь появляется указатель * data на динамическую область памяти которая уже у нас существует и в ней уже находится массив?
2)Тогда что происходит с циклом? Он если у нас ссылку на уже инсуючий массив то мы его Перезаписываем ??? Или каким-то образом у нас создается новый массив с такими же значений (но это не возможно потому что у нас не выделено для него памяти)?
**Как происходит копирование по шагам?** Каждая строка берет с объекта А записывает в себя а затем выполняется код якй скопиювався или оно копирует тики тот массив который записался в объекте А !?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass {
    int * data;
public:
    MyClass(int size) { // Конструктор
        this->data = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = i;
            cout << data[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Вызвался Конструктор : "<< this << endl;
    }
    ~MyClass() { // Деструктор
        cout  << "Вызвался Деструктор : " << this  << endl;
        /*delete[] data; Здесь ошибка по понятным причанам 
    }*/ 
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    MyClass A(10);
    MyClass B(A);
```

}

Comment: Если у вас нет своего конструктора, то в генерируемом компилятором копируется все почленно. Указатель `data` в указатель `data` же, так что в вашем варианте оба объекта указывают на одну и ту же область памяти.

Comment: @Harry я это понимаю.Меня интересует мой цикл.У нас же объекты ссылаются на одну и ту же  область памяти.Но в объекте А мы в память записали наш массив.Теперь когда идет копирование у нас указатель в объекте В идет к нашей памяти что бы записать туда массив а там уже есть массив из объекта А.То получается либо перезаписывается массив либо цикл не отрабатывает?

Comment: Почему цикл должен работать? Здесь `MyClass B(A);` вызывается конструктор `MyClass(const MyClass&)` - в нем нет никакого цикла...

Comment: @Harry стоп.А копия вообще влияет на A?Или у нас просто копируется код но не выполняется.Просто остается нейтрален?

Comment: **Код** не копируется. Если вы не написали свой конструктор - копирование означает просто почленное копирование. Для POD-типов - по сути, побайтовое копирование... В вашем варианте - просто копирование `data` из `A` в `B` и больше ничего. Никакой *ваш* код не выполняется, потому что вы его не писали, его просто нет.

Comment: @Дошло,спасибо)